# How do you generate a random number between 0.xyz and 0.abc?

Tags: matlab, random

In MATLAB, `rand` can be used to generate a random number between 0 and 1. I can scale it to make it lie between 0.01 and 0.02 like so:

```
c=rand;
c=c*0.01+0.01;
```

Is there a better way to generate random number in general in the interval of `0.xyz` and `0.abc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's pretty much the best way to generate a random number that is restricted to a certain range.  Assuming that `0.abc > 0.xyz`, you would simply do:

```
c = (n - m)*rand(N,1) + m;
```

First you would generate `N` random numbers between `[0, n - m]` which is what the first part of the above statement is doing, then with the addition of `m`, this would translate your range so that the values are `[m, n]`.  For your case, `m = 0.xyz` and `n = 0.abc`.

Comment: Does some other language like C++, java have better abilities?

Comment: @giffy - Pretty much all of the programming languages I know restrict random numbers to a certain range using this method... at least from what I have seen (Java, Python, etc.).  There may be functions / methods that allow you to specify what range of random numbers you want to generate and that you don't have to do the above yourself, but I'm very certain that they are simply convenience methods and do what I talked about above under the hood.  BTW, thanks for the accept!